# R and Lapply to import excel documents but ignore some documents that are not correct format

Tags: r, excel, tidyverse, lapply, tidyr

I am new to R as of today so this may be simple, but I can not find a solution anywhere.

I am trying to loop through .xlsx files, format them and then bind them into one dataset I think it is called. It works, however, there are a few files that have different row names and amounts of rows. Which then breaks the formatting and thus ends the loop. I would like these files to be ignored when the formatting and binding happens and possibly printing to the console the name of the file.

This is what I have so for and feel free to ask questions if I don't make sense.

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

setwd("~:/Users/sam/Desktop/Information_engineering/traffic")
my_files <- list.files(pattern = ".xlsx", recursive = TRUE)

traffic_congestion = lapply(my_files, function(i){
  my_data = read_excel(i, sheet = 1, range = "A6:H1446")
  my_data_location = read_excel(i, sheet = 1, range = "A1:A2")
  
  my_data <- na.omit(my_data)
  
  my_data <- pivot_longer(my_data, cols=2:8, names_to = "Date_day", values_to = "Amount")
  colnames(my_data) <- c("times", "dates", "Amount")
  my_data$dates <- excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(my_data$dates))
  my_data$times <- strftime(as.Date(my_data$times), format = "%H:%M:%S")
  my_data <- my_data %>% mutate(location = my_data_location[1])

  my_data
})

traffic_congestion = do.call("rbind.data.frame", traffic_congestion)
```

[This is the top of the spreadsheet that I want to bind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIurh.png)

[This is the top of the spreadsheet that I don't want to bind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1FJp.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(traffic_congestion, fill = T)
```

Comment: Sorry I am very new to R where would I fit that into what I have done

Comment: Instead of your last line